# Express.js middleware not handle default urls like localhost:4200

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I want to handle all requests into middleware

I cant handle url like **localhost:4200**. For **localhost:4200/samethink** works fine.

I tried:

```
app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {});

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {});

app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {});

app.use('', function (req, res, next) {});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {});
```

Comment: You need to write common middleware for all routes ?

Comment: yes..yes..yes..yes..yes

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things about middleware in Express is the order in which they are written/included in your file; the order in which they are executed, given that the route matches also needs to be considered.

For example, in the following code snippet, the first function executes first, then the route handler and then the end function. This example summarizes how to use middleware before and after route handler; also how a route handler can be used as a middleware itself.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//First middleware before response is sent
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   console.log("Start");
   next();
});

//Route handler
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   res.send("Middle");
   next();
});

app.use('/', function(req, res){
   console.log('End');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

[image: middleware execution]

Reference :

- [Using middleware in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application)
- [Order of Middleware Calls](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_middleware.htm)
- [What the heck is a “middleware” in ExpressJS](https://medium.com/@zibon/what-the-heck-is-a-middleware-in-expressjs-8f2661813ecd)

Comment: how ca i execute a middleware for url: localhost:xxxx (thats all, no other action or parameter name)

Comment: I think was a problem from client-side where i have an angular app. My code was not the best so i made same changes. What i want to say is that the code above should work for all request including localhost:XXXX (with no ohter actions or parameter)